# Wordpress Custom User Taxonomies and Meta Data Registration Form

Tags: wordpress, metadata, taxonomy, user-registration, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a whole bunch of things I'm using to accomplish what it is I'm trying to do... but in a nutshell, here is what I'm doing:

I've created custom user taxonomies to denote celebrations (anniversaries, birthdays, etc) When a user signs up (w/ Gravity Forms User Registration), they check which ones they want to be a part of. So, when the form is passed, it's meta data (Gravity Forms only deals with meta data with user registration).

I found a script that takes that meta data and compares it to the taxonomy and if it matches, inserts it. The problem, it was written for a radio button form element, not check boxes. It doesn't support multi-term selection. So, it will only insert one of the selections (the last one selected).

How do I get this script to map to the individual categories in the taxonomy (anniversaries, birthdays, etc), instead of the single taxonomy I registered in Wordpress "anniversary".

```
// Hook Gravity Forms user registration -> Map taxomomy

function map_taxonomy($user_id, $config, $entry, $user_pass) {

    global $wpdb;

// Get all taxonomies
    $taxs = get_taxonomies();

// Get all user meta
    $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta($user_id);

// Loop through meta data and map to taxonomies with same name as user meta key
    foreach ($all_meta_for_user as $taxonomy => $value ) {

        if (in_array ($taxonomy, $taxs) ) {         // Check if there is a Taxonomy with the same name as the Custom user meta key

        // Get term id
            $term_id = get_user_meta($user_id, $taxonomy, true);
            If (is_numeric($term_id)) {             // Check if Custom user meta is an ID

                Echo $taxonomy.'='.$term_id.'<br>';

            // Add user to taxomomy term
                $term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );
                $termslug = $term->slug;
                wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, array( $termslug ), $taxonomy, false);

            }
        }
    }

}
add_action("gform_user_registered", "map_taxonomy", 10, 4);
```

(due to anonymity of the support forum I found it on, I'm unable to contact the author. The  post is here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-gravity-forms-custom-post-types-custom-user-taxonomies)

**Edit For Clarity:**
Currently, this script checks meta against a taxonomy. Is there a way to rewrite it to check against a taxonomy's children?

ie. My registered taxonomy's name is "Dates", with the categories Anniversaries, Birthdays, etc.
This script compares the main registered Taxonomy of "Dates". Can it be modified to compare the Taxonomy's categories, like "Birthday" instead?

Answer (score 0):

The code here isn't what you need to modify, it's the code that is triggering this. In other words, if you're receiving $_POST['data'] somewhere and then calling this function, that's what we'd need to see. In general terms, any input that is going to pass multiple values needs its name declared like: name='something[]' -- the brackets are what tell the form to pass that field as an array of values. On the receiving side you'll need to parse that array and do something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see what you're saying. Unfortunately, I'm not even sure where to begin in finding that particular string of code. Because I'm using Gravity Forms and mapping it to custom user meta with their user registration add on... it could be buried anywhere in the GF plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, and here's what I did...

```
// Hook Gravity Forms user registration -> Map taxomomy

function map_taxonomy($user_id, $config, $entry, $user_pass) {

    global $wpdb;

// Get terms from taxonomy anniversary
    $terms = get_terms( 'anniversary', array('hide_empty' => 0));
    $termslugs = array();
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $i = $term->slug;
        $termslugs[$i] = $term->slug; 
    }   
    $cats = $termslugs;


// Get all user meta
    $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta($user_id);

// Loop through meta data and map to categories with same name as user meta key
    foreach ($all_meta_for_user as $category => $value ) {

        if (in_array ($category, $cats) ) {         // Check if there is a category with the same name as the Custom user meta key

        // Get term id
            $term_id = get_user_meta($user_id, $category, true);
            If (is_numeric($term_id)) {             // Check if Custom user meta is an ID

                echo '<p>'.$user_id.' | '.$category.'='.$term_id.'</p>';

            // Add user to taxomomy term
                $taxonomy = 'anniversary';
                $term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );
                $termslug = $term->slug;
                wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, array( $termslug ), $taxonomy, true);

            }
        }
    }

}
add_action("gform_user_registered", "map_taxonomy", 10, 4);
```

Instead of mapping the taxonomies, this maps a specific taxonomy, and returns the slugs in an array that looks like the taxonomy array. From there it compares the meta data to the slugs, and inserts the term_id into the parent taxonomy.

Right now, it only works if you specifically call your taxonomy by name in 2 places. I'm sure someone smarter than me can figure out how to make it more dynamic.

But if anyone else needs to do this same thing (and if googling was any indication, many do) Stick this code in in your wordpress theme's functions.php - I'm using it with Gravity Form User Registration plugin

Answer (score 0):

What is the user decides to edit the form, is the current will another entry be made into the taxonomy or will the one entry be updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to categorise user, you can try this WordPress [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags/)